# Conditional expectation and partition theorem to find the expectation of the geometric distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I am reading a book on probability and I have trouble understanding how the expectation of the geometric distribution is derived using conditional expectation.

**Partition theorem (total expectation theorem):** If $X$ is a discrete random variable and $\{B_1, B_2, ...\}$ is a partition of the sample space such that $\mathbb{P}(B_i) > 0$ for each $i$. Then $\mathbb{E}(X) = \sum_i \mathbb{E}(X | B_i) \mathbb{P}(B_i)$, whenever this sum converges absolutely.

**Conditional expectation definition:** If $X$ is a discrete random variable and $\mathbb{P}(B) > 0$, the conditional expectation of $X$ is given by $\mathbb{E}(X | B)$ and defined by $\mathbb{E}(X | B) = \sum_{x \in \text{Im} X } x \mathbb{P}(X = x | B)$.

Suppose we have $X \sim Geo(p)$, with pmf $p_X (x) = q^{k-1} p$ for $k \in \mathbb{N}$ and $q = 1-p$. We could derive $\mathbb{E}(X)$ by applying the partition theorem:

$A_1 = \{X = 1\} = \{ \text{first try is a succes} \}$

$A_2 = \{X > 1\} = \{ \text{first try is a failure} \}$

They then go on to show that:

(1) $\mathbb{E}(X | X = 1 ) = 1$

(2) $\mathbb{E}(X | X > 1 ) = 1 + \mathbb{E}(X)$

I do not understand how (1) and (2) are derived, and the book does not show the calculations. When I perform them myself using the definition of conditional expectation, I don't get the same answers. It would help me gain more insight if someone could show how **conditional expectation** is used to derive those results.

Answer (score 1):

Hint

$E(X|X)=X$ so $E(X|X=a)=a$

by definition:

$E(X|A)=\frac{E(X1_A)}{p(A)}$

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation#Conditional_expectation_with_respect_to_an_event

so

$$E(X|X>1)=\frac{E(X1_{X>1})}{p(X>1)}=\frac{\sum_{x>1} x P(X=x)}{p(X>1)}$$

another approach:

$$E(X|X>1)=E(X|A)=\sum x P(X=x|A)=\sum x \frac{P(\{X=x\},\{X>1\})}{P(\{X>1\})}
= \frac{1}{P(\{X>1\})}\sum_{x=1}^{\infty} x P(\{X=x\},\{X>1\})
=\frac{1}{P(\{X>1\})}\left(0+\sum_{x=2}^{\infty} x P(\{X=x\})\right)$$

Comment: My question is how the definition of conditional probability is used to derive the results.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation#Basic_properties

Comment: That still does not show me how it is derived using the definition of conditional expectation, which is the question.

Comment: dear @A B C, you mean need more detail or another approach?

Comment: Another approach, I want to see how the definition of conditional expectation in my post is used to derive (1) and (2). I have tried it myself using that definition, but am doing something wrong.